# PDO query not executing as expected

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am trying to retrieve data from the database. I'm using PDO and the execute statement seems to be giving problems that I can't figure out.

```php
public function doesAdminEmailExist($email){
     $this->m_dbHandler->queryDB("SELECT id FROM Admin WHERE email = ? ", array($email));
     $ret = $this->m_dbHandler->fetchOne();

     if(!empty($ret)) return $ret["id"];
     else return -1;
}
```

The `queryDB` function in another class is given below:

```php
public function queryDB($query, $params=array()){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->m_dbConn->prepare($query);
        if($stmt === false){
            $arr = $this->m_dbConn->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not prepare query: ". $arr[2]." // query: ".$query);
        }
        else {
            $bool_status = $stmt->execute($params);
            if($bool_status){ // Query was successful
                $this->result = $stmt;
            }
            else { // Query was not successful
                $arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
                throw new Exception("Could not execute query: ". $arr[2]." // query: ".$query);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        //throw $e;
        $arr = $this->m_dbConn->errorInfo();
        throw new Exception("An error occurred: ". $arr[2]." // query: ".$query);
    }

}
```

When I run in my browser, I get the following error

```xml
<server_response>
  <return_status>true</return_status>
  <return_message>error Occured. Rethrowing <br>An   error occurred: // query: SELECT id FROM Admin WHERE email = ? </return_message>
</server_response>
```

Comment: $arr probably contains more info under other keys ... dump the whole thing.

Comment: thanks @CBroe for the heads up, I just dumped the whole thing as you suggested and it outputs the following error:                                     3D000  1046  No database selected

Comment: Then that is clearly the issue. Where and how are you connecting to the database and how does that connection relate to what you posted? It looks like the m_dbHandler function might be the suspect.

Comment: thanks all for your help, I got tired of the whole thing and started the project afresh, this time being more careful and observant, everything now works and I'm progressing in the work. I appreciate you guys (cbroe and Dave)